# How to make x variable change each time and read its value from txt file

Tags: control, ros, computer-vision, python, flight-controller

**I am working on my undergraduate project and this is my first time in using use python to control parrot bebop 2 drone and use BCI or BMI technology. 
I have x variable (int) and I want to read its value from file in the main time I want the program read this file continuously what I mean exactly that my text file input will be changed each time and I want the python code to catch this change and change the value x**

**for example:
if x receive 1 from the text file --> then takeoff the drone

in the main time after x receive 1 I want it receives 2 directly (automatically) and do the second command for example: move to the left (but without disconnect the drone "the first command") 
her is my code, but I had a lot of problems with it, its check the value but no commands work after its know the variable of x:**

```
import sys  
import os
from time import sleep
from pyparrot.Bebop import Bebop
import math


#def result(n):
bebop = Bebop()
print("connecting")
success = bebop.connect(10)
print(success) 
f = open('EEGresults.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
list_of_elements = []
for line in lines:
   list_of_elements += map(int, line.split())
f.close()
print (list_of_elements)
x = list_of_elements[1]

bebop.smart_sleep(5)

if x == 1:
   print ("Yay! This number is = 1")
   bebop.safe_takeoff(3)

else:
   if x == 2:
      print ("Yay! This number is = 2")
      bebop.move_relative(0,0,0,1.6)

   else:  
      if x == 3:
         print ("Yay! This number is = 3")

         bebop.smart_sleep(1)
         bebop.safe_land(5)
         print("DONE - disconnecting")
         bebop.disconnect()


print("DONE - disconnecting")
bebop.disconnect()
```

Comment: get as much information as possible about the state of the running program ... print the value of `line` and also the value of `x` ... do you see what you expect to see?

Comment: since x = list_of_elements[1] , when I run the program its give me the correct answer which is 2, which is the second number I wrote it in the text file, but what I need is how I can make x a changed value that can receive a number from the text file automatically and do the commands, e.g, if x == 1 (which is the first number in the file) then takeoff the drone, else if x == 2, then turn left.. etc.